# SNMP TRAPS sending to other file, than /var/log/messages

Tags: syslog, net-snmp, rsyslog, snmp-trap, snmptrapd

I have configuration 
**snmptrapd.conf** like below:

```
disableAuthorization yes
authCommunity log,execute,net public
```

I wanted to redirect all messages for other file, ex. **/var/log/snmp.log**, not for **/var/log/messages**. I tried also reconfigure **rsyslog.conf** file:

```
snmp.*                                              /var/log/snmp.log
```

but I have error like that

```
sie 17 12:50:47 snmp rsyslogd[20398]: unknown facility name "snmp" [v8.24.0]
```

My question is, how to redirect all SNMP traps to other file by using **rsyslog.conf** or **snmptrapd.conf**

I know, that I can save output manually by using command like below, but I need working deamon as a service, not a single command from bash shell.

```
snmptrapd -f -Le -A -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -t option with snmptrapd.

```
snmptrapd -tLf /your-log-location/yourlogfile.log --disableAutherization=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# LOGFILE="path to logfile"
#   specify the pathname of the logfile; if none or the empty string "" is
#   given, use the syslog() mechanism to log the traps
#   Default: ""
```